# Одновременная работа нескольких сессий с одной таблицей

Tags: sql, база-данных, oracle, транзакции

Какая сложится ситуация в таком сценарии:

- Сессия А: `SELECT * FROM TABLE_A` (запускается долгая выборка)
- Сессия Б: `INSERT INTO TABLE_A ...; COMMIT;`
- Сессия А: Запущенная выборка достигает блока, который был вставлен сессией Б
- Сессия А: выборка закончена

Что в таком случае увидит пользователь в сессии А?

Comment: Вроде бы на поверхности вопрос, но что-то никак не нагуглится...

Comment: Искать надо было "read committed". SCN каждого блока, который читается сессией А будет сравнён с SCN на момент открытия курсора. Если не сходятся, то в кэше будут создаваться блоки с откатом через undo, их то и увидит сессия А. Попозже дам более развёрнутый ответ с наглядным примером.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Что в таком случае увидит пользователь в сессии А?

Запрос в сессии А не увидит изменений, которые были произведены и зафиксированы в сессии Б.

> [Read Committed Isolation Level](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/cncpt/data-concurrency-and-consistency.html#GUID-DB571DA8-864F-4FE9-93B9-3EC2DD0604FE)
>   In the read committed isolation level, every query executed by a transaction **sees only data committed before the query — not the transaction — began**.

Этот уровень изоляции транзакций установлен в *Oracle* БД по умолчанию.
В нём БД гарантирует, что данные получаемые из запроса соответствуют их консистентному состоянию (*read consistency*) на **момент начала запроса, не транзакции**. Не важно, как долго длится запрос, явный он или неявный.

Консистентное состояние данных при их чтении достигается сравнением текущего SCN (*system change number*) в БД на момент начала запроса и SCN каждого блока (т.е. последним изменением блока) читаемого запросом. При обнаружении блока с более поздними изменениями, будет создана копия блока в *Buffer cashe*. Данные в копии блока будут последовательно откатываться используя UNDO записи до тех пор, пока SCN не будет равным или более ранним чем SCN запроса.

Наглядно процесс чтения представлен на следующей картинке:

[image: процесс чтения]

Подробнее о доступных  уровнях изоляции транзакций в [офф. документации](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nv4wP.gif).

---

**Воспроизводимый пример**

Подготовим данные в сессии А и откроем курсор для пошагового (`arrays 1`) чтения:

```sql
create table t1 as
    with data (id, memo) as (
        select rownum, 'memo '||rownum from xmlTable ('1 to 3')
    ) select * from data;

set serveroutput on arrays 1    
var mycursor refcursor;
exec open :mycursor for select memo from t1
```

В сессии Б произведём и зафиксируем изменения:

```sql
update t1 set memo = memo||'**' where id=2;

1 row updated.

commit;

Commit complete.
```

В сессии А начнём читать данные:

```sql
declare memo varchar2 (16);
begin
    fetch :mycursor into memo;
    dbms_output.put_line (memo);
end;
/
memo 1
/
memo 2
```

Видно, что курсор возвращает ещё не изменённые данные. Даже если в этой же сессии А изменить данные и продолжить чтение из курсора, то увидим, что данные всё так же ещё не изменены. И только новый запрос в этой же транзакции выведет изменённые данные:

```sql
update t1 set memo = memo||'**' where id=3;

1 row updated.

declare memo varchar2 (16);
begin
    fetch :mycursor into memo;
    dbms_output.put_line (memo);
end;
/
memo 3

select * from t1;

        ID MEMO
---------- ---------------------------------------------
         1 memo 1
         2 memo 2**
         3 memo 3**
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Думаю, путникам в гугле будет интересен этот пост время от времени.

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего ничего не увидит (в смысле не увидит изменений что внесла сессия Б). SELECT будет работать с базой на момент своего запуска.
Вот и документация про это пишет: "The read committed transaction isolation level is the Oracle default.  With this setting, each query can see only data committed before the query..."
http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_oracle_isolation_level.htm