# В каком порядке выполненяются выражения в SET запроса MERGE?

Tags: sql, oracle, transaction

В каком порядке происходит выполнение запроса на слияние данных `MERGE`?

Например:

```
MERGE INTO SCEHMA.TABLE updtab
USING (SELECT * FROM SOURCE_VIEW) fromtab
ON (updtab.key = fromtab.key)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET 
    updtab.field_1 = case when (updtab.field_1 is null) then fromtab.val_1 end,
    updtab.field_2 = case when (updtab.field_1 is null) then fromtab.val_2 end;
```

Будут ли оба условия для `field_1 is null` в SET выполнены сразу, или каждое из них будет выполняться последовательно и второй для `field_2` всегда будет неудачным, поскольку `field_1` больше не будет `NULL` после первой строки `SET`?

Полагаю, что по стандарту SQL выборка всегда выполняется первой. Но это же происходит на этапе обновления, и как в этом случае? Документация не совсем ясна и заставляет задуматься.

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Order of Evaluation - Merge Queries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68410396) от участника [@Greg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13090380/greg)</sub>

Comment: ЕМНИП по стандарту то, что справа от знака присвоения, есть значение до начала обновления. И неважно, является ли источником таблица, представление или подзапрос.

Comment: @Akina Кажется не совсем понял ваш комментарий. По какому стандарту?

Comment: Вот блин, сейчас стал вспоминать, где это было подробно описано - и так и не вспомнил. Помню, там подробно разбиралось, что либо так, либо появляется позиционная зависимость и прощай детерминированность, и именно поэтому такое строгое деление, а не "зависит от реализации".

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/68410396

Comment: Кстати, показательно поведение Оракла в случае, если `fromtab.key` неуникален.

Answer (score 2):

Все происходит в рамках одного запроса `MERGE`. Oracle БД обеспечивает согласованность чтения на уровне запроса, что гарантирует, что данные, возвращаемые одним запросом, зафиксированы и согласованы для одного момента времени. [Statement-Level Read Consistency](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/cncpt/data-concurrency-and-consistency.html#GUID-6A252EAE-7900-47DC-BD6A-D5376A6B7608):

> Oracle Database always enforces **statement-level read consistency**, which guarantees that data returned by a single query is committed and consistent for a single point in time.

В данном случае момент времени - это время, когда запрос был "открыт" - время начала выполнения.

Это значит, что `field_1` воспринимается *всеми* частями запроса `MERGE` с одним и тем же значением до тех пор, пока запрос не завершится. Каждое изменение `field_1` в операторе SET запроса не отражается на его текущем значении в других частях запроса.

Within a single *transaction*, you're correct. In the default read committed isolation level a non-repeatable read is possible. If a `SELECT` statement is re-run and another transaction has committed data then the data read by your first transaction might be different. The `MERGE` is a statement, and not a transaction.

Если бы в пределах одной *транзакции*, то утверждение из вопроса было бы верно. На стандартном уровне изоляции с фиксацией чтения возможно "неповторяющееся чтение". Если запрос`SELECT` выполняется повторно и другая транзакция зафиксировала данные с момента начала первого выполнения, то данные считанные первым и вторым запросом могут отличаться. Но `MERGE` является запросом, а не транзакцией.

---

*Прим.ред.:* пошаговый и воспроизводимый пример, наглядно помогающий понять выше изложенное, уже имеется [в ответе на похожий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1058042/217579).

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68411032) от участника [@Ben](https://stackoverflow.com/users/458741/ben)</sub>